# Need options to keep input fields visible in java on windows 10 using OSK

Tags: java, javafx, windows-10, on-screen-keyboard

Have a tablet-based Java (JavaFX) app on a windows-10 platform that must interact with the built-in OSK (since it cannot be disabled in windows-10 and need to preserve the ability for user to use an OSK with other apps).

The goal is to ensure that input fields are always visible while the user is typing.  Is there any way to a) get from windows the position information of the OSK and the currently selected style (or size)?  b) a mechanism to know whether or not a part of your own window is actually visible to the user (i.e. not covered up by the OSK)?  Using a custom OSK is not an option since the windows OSK can't be disabled. c) Any other thoughts or options would be appreciated